# substring from last match in php?

Tags: php, string, substring

I have string **"katrina.bhuvnesh.jpg"** , I want to get jpg that means substring that matches the last dot(.)

I looked in substr() function but it's not working exactly what I need.

Please give me any function of PHP that matches string from last and returns substring from that point.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) like this:

```
 $extension = pathinfo("katrina.bhuvnesh.jpg", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 function calls:

```
$filename = 'somefile.sometext.jpg';

$type = end(explode('.', $filename));

// $type is now 'jpg'
```

Alternatively, you can use substr:

```
$type = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.'));
```

Comment: Glad it helped... to whoever downvoted, whats the point? Downvoting is for unhelpful answers, not answers that you don't agree with. Edit - Thank you

Comment: The only problem I would like to highlight is in the case of a file without an extension, e.g. `"something"`.

Comment: +1 and removing my dup answer

Comment: Thats true, thanks for point it out @Jack